# How can i move Clearcase dyamic/snapshot views to another host (Linux)

Tags: unix, version-control, clearcase, configuration-management

i'm about to setup a new server that will be dedicated for CC views i'm wondering if there is any way to move the existing views to the new server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory, yes: you can unregister a view (`cleartool untegister` + `cleartool rmtag -view`), and register it again on the new server.

See:

- "[Moving a view to a host with the same architecture or to a NAS device](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_admin.doc%2Ftopics%2Ft_viewadm_mv_1arch.htm)"
- "[Moving a view to a host with a different architecture](https://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_admin.doc/topics/t_viewadm_mv_2arch_ux.htm)": it involves a `cleartool reformatview -dump/-load` in addition of the unregister/register steps.

(after the more general page "[About moving ClearCase servers](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21129835)")

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, in the past, I've just found it easier to throw away views and start over.  We used a standard set of config specs that created task-specific branches per view.  We worked with dynamic views (if you're working with snapshot views in clearcase, I think that you're using the wrong Version Control System), but had our developers checkin all of their changes (which by default would checkin against their feature branch), we'd then delete all of the views for the host being decommisioned, and had developers re-create their views normally (which would automatically start them up on the new server).  We naturally abstracted away a lot of the customized config specs and setting up metadata for them so they only needed to run a simple command to continue.

We were *not* using UCM, however.

Now that I think about it, we just had a small handful of scripts that were used to do this work - basically wraps all of the dirty "view" details away from the developers (which honestly, they don't need to know about in general).