# How to move base clearcase view (dynamic) to another host

Tags: clearcase

I have 6 base clearcase views on one host i want to move them to another host.
What is the best way of doing it ?
I have a preconfigured specfile in every view i'll need to copy this spec file as well.
Lets say that the views currently located on hostname: "test1" and i want to move them to "test2"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chaging the view storage path is easy on the same server ("[Moving the view storage location of a web view](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21150413)")

But moving from one view server to another server is more complex (see "[Moving a view to a host with a different architecture](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_admin.doc/topics/t_viewadm_mv_2arch_ux.htm)").
It would involve a `cleartool reformatview -dump/-load` I mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25228819/6309).

Sometime, it is easier to delete them in one server, and simply re-create them in the other.